# Ranges of enum members that dwim

Tags: enum, raku

Inspired by this [blogpost](https://shintakezou.blogspot.com/2019/10/enumeration-enum-in-perl6.html) I decided to try and make it possible to have ranges of `enum` members that dwim, aka. that contain the actual members and not a stringified form.

This is the result. I'm looking for comments and wether I overlook a pitfall. Also, maybe `EnumMember` subset can be expressed in a more performant way?

```
use Test;

subset EnumMember of Any where .HOW.^name eq "Perl6::Metamodel::EnumHOW";

multi sub infix:<..>( EnumMember $a, EnumMember $b ) 
{
    die "Can only do ranges for members of the same enum" unless $a.WHAT === $b.WHAT;
    $a.WHAT.^enum_value_list.grep({ $_ === $a fff $_ === $b })
}

enum Foo ( XA => 17, XB => 19, XC => 2, XD => 17, XE => 1, XF => 99 );
enum Goo < YA YB >;

is-deeply( ( XC..XE ).Array, [XC, XD, XE] ); 
dies-ok({ XA..YB });
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably, you could do something similar by `...` and `succ`.

```perl
enum Foo ( XA => 17, XB => 19, XC => 2, XD => 17, XE => 1, XF => 99 );
enum Goo < YA YB >;
XC, *.succ ... XE andthen .say
```

Thus your example could be rewritten

```perl
use Test;

subset EnumMember of Enumeration; 

multi sub infix:<..>( EnumMember:D ::T $a, T:D $b ) {
    $a, *.succ ... $b 
}

multi sub infix:<..>( EnumMember $a,  $b ) {
    die 'Can only do ranges for members of the same enum' 
}

enum Foo ( XA => 17, XB => 19, XC => 2, XD => 17, XE => 1, XF => 99 );
enum Goo < YA YB >;

is-deeply( ( XC..XE ).Array, [XC, XD, XE] ); 
dies-ok({ XA..YB });
```

But you get `Seq`, not `Range`. So I prefer redefine the sequence operator `...` and make a new role instead of a subtype.

```perl
use Test;

role EnumMember {}; 

multi sub infix:<...>( EnumMember:D ::T $a, T:D $b ) {
    $a, *.succ ... $b 
}

multi sub infix:<...>( EnumMember $a,  $b ) {
    fail 'Can only do sequence for members of the same enum' 
}

multi sub infix:<…>( EnumMember $a,  $b ) {
  $a ... $b
}

enum Foo does EnumMember ( XA => 17, XB => 19, XC => 2, XD => 17, XE => 1, XF => 99 );
enum Goo does EnumMember < YA YB >;

is (XC … XE), (XC, XD, XE); 
dies-ok { XA … YB };
```